# Get 404 on remote server but can open page on local server

Tags: php, curl, centos, http-status-code-404, phpmailer

I'm having issues with the following code. It is supposed to send an email to the email server provider. It's working perfectly fine on the local server, but when I test it on the remote server, I always get:

```
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
```

Any idea on why this is happening is hugely appreciated.

Code:

```
 public function index ()
 {   
    $recipient = $email;
    $title = 'You've got mail';
    $body = 'I love you!';

    $data=
    array(
    'api_user'=>'postmaster@sendcloud.org',
    'api_key' =>'password',
    'from'=>'raphael.luo@live.com',
    'to'=>$recipient,
    'subject'=>$title,
    'html'=>$body
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://sendcloud.sohu.com/webapi/mail.send.json');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);       

     $result = curl_exec($ch); 

     curl_close($ch);

    print_r($result);

}
```

Comment: I installed curl on both servers.

Comment: You have syntax errors on single quotes, and You are getting that error on web page? Or your are using it from commandline. Give more detail

Answer (score 0):

It could be the problem with secure commnunication(your url has `https://`). So, if you do not have any problem to use insecure communication, then add this curl option with your code and try again:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
```

Also its is always safe to use `http_build_query` function for the `POST` data.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```